# vertically align the image as of the texts

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following html....

```
<div>
    <img src="" /> 
    <span>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
    </span>
</div>
```

And the css....

```
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle; /* not worked.... */
}
span{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGg6H/11/)

As you can see in the demo the red box to which I want to align vertically to the texts. I can also give the height of the div for eg 400px.

Comment: Do you want image to be inline with text?

Comment: yes, the image is inline with text....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to do this I'd use a table display (which works on [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)).

First, change your markup to wrap your `img` in a `span` of its own (this will act as our table cell):

```html
...
<span>
    <img />
</span>
<span>
    ...
</span>
```

Then apply the following styling:

```css
div {
    display:table;
}

span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-left:10px;
}

span:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}

img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#f00;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/KGg6H/13/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve a similar result using absolute positioning of the red square motif using the following CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
}
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
span{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Set `position: relative` on the parent container and then use absolute positioning to place the `img` 50% from the top and then apply `margin-top: -25px` to vertically align it with respect to the parent container's height.

You need to set the text `margin-left: 60px` on the `span` to allow room for the square motif.

The one advantage is that the design does not rely on `display: table-cell`.

The one disadvantage is that for text blocks that are less than 50px in height, the text will be aligned to the top edge of the square, which may not be suitable depending on the design requirements.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/796us/

**Footnote:** Personally, I think `display: table-cell` is a more robust solution as long as the browser supports it.  If `table-cell` is not supported, then the design would degrade gracefully to the motif being aligned to the top edge of the text block, which is on par with the absolute positioning option's limitation with short text blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` property allowed only for `table` elements or for elements wich displayed as `table-cell` as mentioned James Donelly in his answer, 
but as alternative you can use:

`margin-top: 50%;` see example:
http://jsfiddle.net/KGg6H/19/